# Run a cronjob every 5 minutes on weekdays between 9:30AM to 15:30PM?

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I have read the answers and I am not able to get an explanation whether this expression will work:

```
*/5 930-1530 * * 1-5 <command>
```

I am trying to run a script every 5 minutes between 9:15AM to 15:30PM only on weekdays

New to `cron` and `ubuntu`

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Put it on three separate lines.

Answer (score 5):

```
30-59/5 9 * * 1-5 <command>
0-30/5 15 * * 1-5 <command>     
*/5 10-14 * * 1-5 <command>
```

Try it (like in your comments) with three separate tabs.

Comment: Thanks guys, I have set it up and will be able to test it out tomorrow. If I could get a more detailed explanation of the lines I would be greatful. If I understand them correctly: First line, minute 30 to 59, every 5 minutes during the 30-59 range, hour = 9? second line, minute 0-30, every 5 minutes, at hour 15. last line every 5 minutes from 10am to 3PM(as the range is inclusive?)

Answer (score 1):

9:30 to 15:30

```
30/5 9-15 * * 1-5
```

You also can use this tool for generate right configuration line: https://crontab.guru

If you need 9:15 to 15:30, then use:

```
15/5 9-16 * * 1-5
```

But it start from 9:15 to 16:15, now inside script you need check current time and stop the script execution, if time bigger than 15:30. I know its ugly way, because from 15:30 to 16:15 u will have 9 waste calls your script.

upd.
Another variant:

```
15/5 9-15 * * 1-5
20-30/5 15 * * 1-5
```

Here we start from 9:15 - 15:15, last call at 15:15, so next line start from 15:20 - 15:30. I think it's a better way.